# Objective c or c++?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, ios, programming-languages

i was just curious to know if all the codes provided by Apple is the ios dev library, and by the forums are objective c or c++. What exactly is the difference between the two? 
Which one works in Xcode?

Comment: Please remove the "another thing... is there..." phrase from this question and put it in a separate question. On Stack Overflow, only one question should be asked in each post.

Comment: This question is hard to read.  The question I think you are asking is "Are C++ and objective C the only languages provided by Apple"? Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Obj-C and C++ are extensions of the C language. Both wanted to do the same - extend C with objects.

C++ is much more complex and currently much more popular on every non-Apple system.

Both work in Xcode. Actually you can combine Obj-C and C++ in one program (Obj-C++).

The differences between the languages are great - objects are declared, allocated and freed differently. Not only the syntax is different, they were designed differently (Operator overriding, access rights, multiple inheritance, templates in C++; Message sending, categories, properties, reference counting, protocols in Obj-C).

It's hard to explain the differences, if you don't know anything about either of them.
Obj-C is easier to learn (it's much simpler).
For both languages, you need to know C well.

EDIT: most of the code in iOS dev library is either pure C or Obj-C

Comment: I do not agree that you need to know C to learn C++ or Objective-C

Comment: With C++ it is a little more difficult but you can't do anything in Obj-C without C. Did you ever used a `CGPoint` or a `CGRect`? They are C structs, not Obj-C objects. Have you ever used `NSLog`? It's a C function, not an Obj-C method. Have you ever used `#define`? That's C preprocessor. Have you ever used an `enum`? Obj-C tutorials teach C without saying it's C. Then people can't see the difference but you can't write ANY Obj-C program without some C knowledge.

Comment: well there is a difference between "to know C well" and "some C knowledge"

Comment: The difference is "to be good in Obj-C or C++ you have to know C well" and "for a simple program you need intermediate C knowledge".
`if`s, `while`s, `for`s, `switch`es - almost everything inside a method body is C.

Comment: You can certainly "get-by" for a while in Obj-C without knowing much "hard C", but you'll never play pro-ball. However, C is procedural and Obj-C is OOP - so spending years "learning C first" is also a bad idea, as it's a different way of doing things, though eventually you'll have to learn both. For now, what you really need is to learn "Just Enough C" to get past this barrier. I strongly recommend "Beginning Mac OX Snow Leopard Programming", chapter 6 "The C Programming Language", which it explains in this context - it's a little out of date - but it's still great to get you over this hump.